# Dynamically change Input values after adding CollectionType Entity - Symforny Form CollectionType

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm currently working on a Project using Symfony 5, Twig & Doctrine, that has Teams and Members with Team Roles. 
 I can already add Members/remove Members due to the CollectionType from Symfony Form. 
**I want to achieve following:** E*verytime the Web User clicks on "add Member" Button after the creating of a new Input form, I want to update the selectable users to add. Because if you already added a user, it should not show up, regardless if they are already in the team or if they are only added to the Collection Forms via Javascript.*

Relation:

```
Team <- OneToMany-> Membership <- ManyToOne -> User
```

Team, Membership, User are Entities.
Team & User has some default stuff and a $memberships. Membership has $role, $user, $team.
A Membership Entity holds the Realtion between a Team and an User(Member) with his given team Role.

*Now I have a form to add/remove Members from the team with given Role.*

```
<div class="card w-75 mx-auto pm-header-content">
  <h1 class="mb-2 text-center">Quick and easy, add new Members.</h1>
  <a href="{{ path('dashboard_team', {'team_id': team.id}) }}" class="link-dark mx-auto">Back to Team</a>
  <div class="container mx-auto bg-light p-4 rounded mb-4 mt-4 w-75 h-100" style="width: auto;">
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {% do form.memberships.setRendered %}
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
    <div class="card p-5 container">
      <div class="card-title">
        <h5>Team Members</h5>
        <p>Here you can manage Members and add new Members.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-text pm-teamMemberships-card bg-light rounded" id="pm-teamMemberships-list" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.memberships.vars.prototype)|escape('html_attr') }}" data-widget-counter="{{ form.memberships|length }}" data-widget-tags="{{ '<div class="pm-teamMemberships-panel panel mt-3 mb-0" id="pm-teamMemberships-panel"><div class="card-body"></div><div class="pm-teamMemberships-footer p-2"></div></div>'|e }}">
        {% for item in form.memberships %}
        <div class="pm-teamMemberships-panel panel mt-3 mb-0">
          <div class="card-body">
            {{ form_row(item) }}
          </div>
          <div class="pm-teamMemberships-footer p-2"></div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <hr>
      <span style="width: 200px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary pm-teamMemberships-addBtn btn-block" data-list-selector="#pm-teamMemberships-list">Add Member</button>
      </span>
    </div>
    <p class="mx-auto text-center m-0" style="color: #8d8d8ddd;">* Inputs need to be filled</p>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-light pm-project-create-btn mx-auto" type="submit" id="btn-project-label">
    Submit
  </button>
  {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

*The JQuery Script that handles the Add/Remove Buttons inside Template Form (CollectionType):*

```
// add-collection-widget.js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(".pm-teamMemberships-addBtn").click(function (e) {
    var list = jQuery(jQuery(this).attr("data-list-selector"));
    // Try to find the counter of the list or use the length of the list
    var counter = list.data("widget-counter") || list.children().length;

    // grab the prototype template
    var newWidget = list.attr("data-prototype");
    // replace the "__name__" used in the id and name of the prototype
    // with a number that's unique to your emails
    // end name attribute looks like name="contact[emails][2]"
    newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, counter);
    // Increase the counter
    counter++;
    // And store it, the length cannot be used if deleting widgets is allowed
    list.data("widget-counter", counter);

    // create a new list element and add it to the list
    var newElem = jQuery(list.attr("data-widget-tags")).html(newWidget);
    newElem.appendTo(list);
    tinymce.init(options);
    // finally add remove button
    addTaskFormDeleteLink(newElem);
  });
  // add remove button once to all already existing tasks
  const tasks = document.querySelectorAll("div.pm-teamMemberships-panel");

  tasks.forEach((task) => {
    addTaskFormDeleteLink(task);
  });
});

const addTaskFormDeleteLink = (tagFormLi) => {
  const removeFormButton = document.createElement("button");
  removeFormButton.classList;
  removeFormButton.innerText = "Remove Member";
  removeFormButton.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-danger");

  tagFormLi.append(removeFormButton);

  removeFormButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // remove the li for the tag form
    tagFormLi.remove();
  });
};
```

*The View looks like this:*
[Template Team Members Manage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgBUY.png)

*Okay the Controller looks like this:*

```php
/**
 * loads an invitation page and handles for a team with given Request
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function loadInviteAction(Request $request):Response
{

    $team = $this->teamRepository->find($request->get('team_id'));
    if(empty($team)){
        $this->addFlash('error', 'Das Team wurde nicht gefunden.');
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('dashboard_teams'));
    }
    $originalMembers = new ArrayCollection();
    foreach($team->getMemberships() as $member){
        $originalMembers->add($member);
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(TeamInvite::class, $team);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

        foreach($form['memberships']->getData() as $membership){
            if(!$originalMembers->contains($membership) ){
                $this->entityManager->persist($membership);
                $this->addFlash('success', "Der Nutzer ". $membership->getUser()->getUuid()." wurde zum Team hinzugefügt.");
            }
        }
        foreach($originalMembers as $membership){
            if(!$form['memberships']->getData()->contains($membership)){
                $team->getMemberships()->removeElement($membership);
                $this->entityManager->persist($team);
                $this->entityManager->remove($membership);
                $this->addFlash('success', "Der Nutzer ". $membership->getUser()->getUuid()." wurde vom Team entfernt.");
            }
        }
        $this->entityManager->persist($team);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('dashboard_team', ['team_id'=>$team->getId()]));
    }
    return $this->render('Team/addMember.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'team'=> $team
    ]);
}
```

*Lastly the two FormTypes:*

```php
# src/Form/Type/MembershipType
class MembershipType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user', EntityType::class, [
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) {
                    return $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->leftJoin('u.memberships', 'm', 'WITH', 'm.team = :team')
                        ->andWhere('m.id IS NULL')
                        ->setParameter('team', 41);
                },
                'class'=>User::class,
                'choice_label'=>'uuid',
                'required'=>true
            ])
            ->add('role', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'=> [
                    'Member'=>'ROLE_TEAM_USER',
                    'Admin'=>'ROLE_TEAM_ADMIN'
                ],
                'required'=>true,
                'label'=>false
            ])
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
       $resolver->setDefaults([
           'data_class'=>Membership::class
       ]);
    }

}
```

*and the main TeamInvite(with CollectionType) Type Form:*

```php
# src/Form/Type/TeamInvite
class TeamInvite extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('memberships',CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type'=>MembershipType::class,
                'entry_options'=> [
                    'label'=>false
                ],
                'label'=> 'add Member',
                'allow_add'=>true,
                'allow_delete'=>true,
                'by_reference'=>false
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
       $resolver->setDefaults([
           'data_class'=>Team::class
       ]);
    }

}
```

I need to update the created Form everytime when clicked on btn "Add Member", so that only the not already selected users are shown. I think I need to call everytime a AJax request, to get the new selectable users.

1. You are not allowed to select multiple times the same user

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: You have some JS work to do. When you add a new user, you should loop through the select options, and remove an option if it has just been chosen (you can compare "value" attr to get matches). When you remove a user, you should put the option back (for this reason, it's better to have a prototype for all options, or "remember" what you are deleting so you can restore it). Otherwise, you have to rewrite the whole approach to AJAX, which will take pretty much time for you.

Comment: Thanks, I think I know what to do and how to get it working!